# NGINX basic auth only for POST

Tags: nginx, mercurial, http-basic-authentication

I'm settings up nginx to serve Mercurial repositories. It works when not using basic authentication at all, or when I use basic authentication all over.

What I want to do is to just use basic auth on POST requests, so anyone have pull access, but only authenticated users can push.

I tried the following,

```
if ($request_method = POST) {
  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file /path/to/userfile
}
```

However it complains about "auth_basic directive is not allowed here".

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 16):

You should use [`limit_except`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#limit_except):

```
limit_except GET HEAD {
    auth_basic 'Restricted';
    auth_basic_user_file /path/to/userfile;
}
```

It works since nginx 0.8.48, in older versions there was a bug where `fastcgi_pass` was not inherited inside the limit_except block.